# how to append element in list while dynamically rendering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to show a list of messages which are in an array. In that list element contains a child element of "div". there need append more div in that child elements based on cases using the id of that particular div.

But i've getting null from both **document.getElementById** and **React.createRef()** methods. I've tried below sample source,

```
this.state.messageDetail.map((message, index) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment key={index}>
      {(index === 0 ||
        this.isSameDate(
          message.created_ts,
          this.state.messageDetail[index - 1].created_ts
        )) && (
        <li className="date">
          <span>{moment.unix(message.created_ts).format("MMM DD, YYYY")}</span>
        </li>
      )}
      {(index === 0 ||
        this.isSenderAndTimeSame(
          message.sender_id,
          message.created_ts,
          index
        )) && (
        <li className="user" ref={this.userDetailRef}>
          <React.Fragment>
            <div className="img">
              <img
                alt=""
                src={
                  message.sender_id === null
                    ? CURRENT_USER_IMAGE
                    : BUCKET_PATH + "/" + this.state.currentTimeline.image
                }
              />
            </div>
            <div id={"user_detail_" + index} className="details">
              <div className="details-header">
                <span className="userName">
                  {message.sender_id === null
                    ? CURRENT_USER_NAME
                    : this.state.currentTimeline.name}
                </span>
                <span className="time">
                  {moment.unix(message.created_ts).format("hh:mm A")}
                </span>
              </div>
              <div className="message">{message.message_body}</div>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        </li>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});
```

In the above sample **isSenderAndTimeSame** method will create and append a **new child element** by find div id (ie.**user_detail_3**). I am getting null value.
Kindly suggest your best way to do it.

I'm adding a UI image:

[image: ui image]

Comment: Do you want to append the div dynamically during run-time or while rendering and running your map function?

Comment: Don't do this (use `document.getElementById` in a ReatJS app). Instead, you should create the element in JSX.

Comment: @PrakharMittal while rendering and when my map function is running

Comment: @TecoreDemo then you don't need ```document.getElemenById```. Just write it in the place where you want to insert the div.

Comment: @PrakharMittal but I want to insert the div in the previously added list in the loop, not in the current list.

Comment: @TecoreDemo Can you provide a running snippet of it? It would be easy to understand and provide a solution for it.

Comment: @PrakharMittal can I add an image of the UI.

Comment: @TecoreDemo Let's try with that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208111/discussion-between-prakhar-mittal-and-tecore-demo).